# On transactions and event listeners

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions

Let me see if I understand this correctly. Normally, we should strive to put all operations which belong to one "unit of work" under the same transaction, right? This helps revert the state of the DB in case of an exception somewhere along the chain of operations.

However, in my particular case, I have an old service, which is not really easy to plug into my current code. Therefore I have to keep it running separately, and give it rights to the same database where my current application stores data.

The problem comes when I have to insert a new item into the DB. Then I have to call the service. If I do this under one transaction, the service will start looking for a record in the DB, before the transaction has actually committed. Thus, I started using event listeners, namely the PostInsertEventListener and the PostDeleteEventListener.

Now it works OK, since the transaction commits beforehand, but this totally disrupts my code architecture. I have built a series of services which inject into each other, and now I have to declare those two listener classes. I guess, the best I can do is to make my coordinator service implement those two listener interfaces, but in this way I totally couple it to Hibernate, right?

In general, is using those listeners really the right way for cases like mine?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how you came from *"I need to have the transaction committed before calling the external service"* to *"I decided using listeners"*.

Why don't you simply have the following code:

```
public void someNonTransactionalMethod() {
    someTransactionalService.insertThingsInDatabase();
    externalService.foo();
}
```

or

```
public void someMethod() {
    someTransactionalService.insertThingsInDatabase();
    externalService.foo();
}
```

where `insertThingsInDatabase` uses the `REQUIRES_NEW` propagation type?